# How to get warnings about invalid css values

Tags: css, postcss

I am migrating from sass to postcss. To make it easier, I am using `postcss-simple-vars`, which supports similar variables like sass does.

My problem is:

```
$size: 100px;

.class {
    width: $size * 2;
}
```

Sass result:

```
.class {
    width: 200px;
}
```

Postcss with simple vars result:

```
.class {
    width: 100px * 2;
}
```

The latter seems to be invalid css code. In order to fix it, I need to use the `calc()` function. The problem is to find all the occurances of those calculations in my code. I have ~ 1 MB of scss...

Is there any tool (linter, compiler, etc) which would analyze my css and warn me of all the places where this needs to be taken care of?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if there is a pre-build plugin ready to use. But you can create a simple task in gulp and point at any error on your css file.

create your new task in your in your gulp tasks and console.log the errorInfo from your style.css file using toString() method

etc

```
gulp.task('styles' function() {
  return gulp.src('your src ./path for your style.css ')
    .on('error', function(errorInfo) {
     console.log(errorInfo.toString());
     this.emit('end');
 })
   .pipe(gulp.dest('your dest ./path four final destination path '));
});
```

> Updating

```
var processors = function() {
    return function(css) {
      css.eachDecl('width', function(decl) {
          decl.value = decl.value + ', calc({{ size }} * 2)';
      });
    }
};

gulp.task('css', function() {
  return gulp.src('./app/assets/styles/your_style.css')
    .pipe(postcss([processors]))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/temp/styles/'));
 });
```

Comment: Where exactly is the css validated in this function?

Comment: @Karolis am not sure if you;re using the gulp in your workflow. you may find the documetation [here](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/v3.9.1/docs/API.md) to install it The above function can point your syntax errors in your CSS file on your console [imghere](http://oi68.tinypic.com/254zcaq.jpg)

Comment: gulp.src() just reads the file. In order to get a warning about css errors, I would have to pipe the contents to another function which does the processing. Your provided example doesn't do that.

Comment: @Karolis sorry for the misunderstanding. If I understand correctly your trying to replace the `width: 200px * 2;`  to >  `width: calc(200px *2);` ?   what about  the following: 
`function(css) {
 css.eachDecl('width', function(decl) {
  decl.value = decl.value + ', calc($size * 2)';
 });
}`

Comment: You shouldn't be throwing guesses as answers. If you don't know the answer to the question, just skip it.

Comment: @Karolis with all my respect but you have asked the following `Is there any tool (linter, compiler, etc) which would analyze my css and warn me of all the places where this needs to be taken care of?` 'I assumed to warm you for errors.. Correct? And I have ask for that do you remember? ' Why you didn't anwser my question?  I don't know your question my friend how is possible to anwser it??